# Zsh: complete the files in current directory no matter what command is

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, zsh-completion

For example, when I just want to make cfiles without makefile:

```
$ make a<tab>
a1.c  a2.c  a3.c  ...
```

or run the script like:

```
$ ./a<tab>
a1  a2  a3  ...
```

but seems that zsh would detect the command then completes nothing when I hit tab.

It works fine on bash that just lists everything.

Is there the ways like bash do?

My OS is macOS mojave with zsh 5.7.1.

Comment: zsh is trying to be smarter, by only offering completions that would be valid. Since you can't use a `.c` file as a command, it makes no sense to complete it at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Anyway, you should ask this on [unix.se] or [su], it's not a programming question.

Comment: Oh, that's not what I meant, I edited it.

Comment: OK, I'll ask there. Thanks for your advice.